# Calling service method from its class

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-service

I have a service from which I instationate my `ScreenReceiver` class. How can I notify service when `OnRecieve` method of `ScreenReceiver` is triggered? I'd like the `update()` method to be called when 'onRecieve` is trigerred.

StateChecker.java (draft):

```
public class StateChecker extends Service {
   //...
   // setting TimeAlarm
   TimeAlarm mTimeAlarm = new TimeAlarm();
   mTimeAlarm.SetAlarm(this.getApplicationContext(),10);

   public void update() {
   //update sth
   }
   //...
}
```

ScreenReceiver.java (draft):

```
public class ScreenReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    //...   

   @Override
   public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    //...
    PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
   }
    //...
}
```

Comment: Both answers are great. I can't accept two answers, so I ticked the one I've used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably do something like this:

Make a new `Intent` to your `Service` from the `Receiver`, passing off an Extra, then override `onStartCommand()` in the Service. Check the intent for the Extra, and if the Extra exists, call `update()`.

Also, if you use `this` instead of `this.getApplicationContext()`, it is very likely that your `Receiver`'s `onReceive()` `Context` parameter will be the service. Then you can just cast.

Eg

```
if (context instanceof StateChecker)
  ((StateChecker) context).update();
```

Answer (score 1):

Define an interface and use a callback to let the activity know that a screen event has been received.

```
public Interface ScreenReceiverListener {
    void onScreenReceive(int arg1, string arg2); ..<----add arguments you want to pass back
}
```

In your ScreenReceiver class

```
ArrayList<ScreenReceiveListener > listeners = new ArrayList<ScreenReceiveListener >();

...

public void setScreenReceiveListener(ScreenReceiveListener listener){
    listeners.add(listener);
}
```

In your OnReceive

```
for (ScreenReceiveListener listener:listeners){
   listener.onSCreenReceive(arg1, arg2);
}
```

In your Service:

```
public class StateChecker extends Service implements ScreenReceiveListener {

    ...

    screenReceiver.setScreenReceiveListener(this);

    ...
}

public void onScreenReceive(int arg1, string arg2){
   // do whatever you need to do
}
```

All from memory so please excuse typos and you should improve the ScreenReceiver class by adding removeScreenReceiveistener and checking that you do not add the same listener twice in setScreenReceiveListener.

Note.  Because you use an interface, any class (not just a Service) can implement it so you can update anywhere in your app.  The ScreenReceiver class doesn't know or care.  It just calls the listeners, if any are registered.

Comment: Thanks. Although I probably don't need now such a powerfull tool, I'll try to implement this anyway (It might be usefull in the future). Could you explain what is going on here:    `for (ScreenReceiveListener listener:listeners){
   listener.onSCreenReceive(arg1, arg2);
}` please?

Comment: Sorry, only just seen this comment.  This is looping through all registered listeners (added in `setScreenReceiveListener`) and invoking the onScreenReceive callback of those listeners.  arg1 and arg2 are whatever data you want to pass to the listeners.