# Where to manipulate views in android app?

Tags: android

I have a MainActivity, which creates MyOwnTextToSpeech object which is responsible for some tts stuff. It also has to manipulate some UI views (e.g. set text in some TextViews). How should I implement this manipulations of UI? Is it good idea to pass reference to MainActivity to MyOwnTextToSpeech (and other objects) and prepare some public methods in MainActivity for manipulating UI or maybe I should create getters for all views (TextView etc.) to have access to them? Or maybe there is a way not to pass reference to MainActivity (I read somewhere that passing reference to Activities is not good because of some memory leaks stuff)?

**UPDATE**

```
        public class MainActivity extends Activity {
           @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            MyOwnTextToSpeech myTts = new MyOwnTextToSpeech(context);
        }
}
```

And my class responsible for tts.

```
public class MyOwnTextToSpeech implements TextToSpeech.OnInitListener {

    private TextToSpeech tts;

    public MyOwnTextToSpeech (Context ctx) {
        tts = new TextToSpeech(ctx, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onInit(int status) {
        if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {

            tts.setOnUtteranceProgressListener(new UtteranceProgressListener() {

                @Override
                public void onStart(String utteranceId) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(String utteranceId) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onDone(final String utteranceId) {

                    // here I want some UI update stuff

                }
            });
            int result = tts.setLanguage(new Locale("pl", "PL"));
            if (result == TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA
                    || result == TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED) {
                Log.e("TTS", "This Language is not supported");
            }

        } else {
            Log.e("TTS", "Initilization Failed!");
        }

    }
```

Comment: None of these, all bad.  Read about Java `Interface` and implement your own callback methods.

Comment: I know about Interfaces and callbacks. Can you show me on my code (update) how should it be done? Just pass an extra parameter to MyOwnTextToSpeech contructor with callback like new Callback() {
   void callback() {
      myTextView.setText("my text");
   }
}

Comment: See my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14540346/calling-service-method-from-its-class/14540424#14540424